# Best way to selectively enable execution steps for a play in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to make Ansible roles as reusable as possible by being able to selectively choose execution steps with tags. So far I've failed to find something appropriate.

Here's what I've tried for a role enabling security updates on a linux machine:

Roles excerpt:

```
- name: Copy the 20auto-upgrades templates to enable automatic security updates
  copy:
    src: 20auto-upgrades
    dest: /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: 0644
  become: yes

- name: Copy the 50unattended-upgrades templates to configure security updates with AUTOMATIC REBOOT
  copy:
    src: 50unattended-upgrades-reboot
    dest: /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: 0644
  become: yes
  tags: 
    - reboot

- name: Copy the 50unattended-upgrades templates to configure security updates with NO AUTOMATIC REBOOT
  copy:
    src: 50unattended-upgrades-noreboot
    dest: /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: 0644
  become: yes
  tags:
    - noreboot
```

I used to have a loop to copy these 2 files, but the fact that I need to be able to activate/deactivate autoreboot after security upgrade made me split it into 3 identical steps. I wish there would be a less verbose way.

Then since it's a role and I want to be able to run it independently, I need to create a specific playbook:

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
  - name: run security-upgrade role with 'noreboot' option
    include_role:
      name: security-upgrades
```

This works well, but I can't seem to be able to execute only one of the two last steps that should be mutually exclusive.
Adding `tags:` to the playbook is not useful, it doesn't enable me to selectively execute one option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `when: security-upgrades_noreboot is defined` and `when: security-upgrades_noreboot is undefined` with your tasks respectively. You will need to pass the variable in the playbook and have it run one task or the other:

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
  - name: run security-upgrade role with 'noreboot' option
    include_role:
      name: security-upgrades
    vars: 
      security-upgrades_noreboot: yes
```

This should skip the task that has `when: security-upgrades_noreboot is undefined`. If you don't pass the var, this task will run, but the other one is skipped.

Comment: Thanks Grigory, that's what I was looking for.
I guess another way would be to have a conditional on a variable in a jinja template for the `50unattended-upgrades`. Then I would probably be able to keep the loop on files to be copied and avoid repetition of identical steps.